# Prove that $A_2 = QA_1 P$ for some invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$, show in particular that $P$ and $Q$ are invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T$ be in $L(V,W)$, let $\mathcal{B}_1$, $\mathcal{B}_2$ be two bases for $V$, and let $\mathcal{C}_1$, $\mathcal{C}_2$ be two bases for $W$. Let $A_1 = M_{\mathcal{B}_1,\mathcal{C}_1}(T)$ and $A_2 = M_{\mathcal{B}_2,\mathcal{C}_2}(T)$. Prove that $A_2 = QA_1 P$ for some invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$, where you provide a construction for $P$ and $Q$ (and show in particular that $P$ and $Q$ are invertible). In the case that $V =W$, $\mathcal{C}_1 = \mathcal{B}_1$,and $\mathcal{C}_2 = \mathcal{B}_2$, show that additionally $Q = P^{-1}$.

I tried to construct 2 change of basis from B1 to B2 and from C1 to C2 such that A2 = first one * A1 * the second one

and then set Q = first one and P = second one

But I'm not sure if this gonna work and how to prove them are invertible

Comment: Have you tried the case where $\mathcal{C}_i = \mathcal{B}_i$? This is treated at some length in many textbooks. Might be a good place to start because it removes one aspect of the input data from the problem.

Comment: Please do not post homework/exam questions word for word verbatim. And please make some effort and show what tools you have to approach problems; we can't be mind readers, and nor do most of us intend to do all your work for you.